# Count the number of rows in MySQL table with criteria depending on other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got two tables:

```
content:
id    access
1     3
2     5
3     9

viewlevels:
id   group
1    [10,12,15]
2    [8,12,11]
3    [9,10,5]
```

The access field in content is related with the id field in viewlevels.

I select the rows in viewlevels depending on the current user group. So for example, if group is = 10, my query will select rows 1 and 3. If the group is 12, it will select rows 1 and 2, etc. I'm using the following query:

```
$query="SELECT id FROM #__viewlevels WHERE rules LIKE '%$group%'";
```

My challenge is to count the number of rows for column id in table content where the access matches with the selected id's from the above query on table viewlevels.

I tried the following code but it is returning the error: undefined variable: nartigos

```
$query="SELECT count(id) FROM #__content WHERE access IN (SELECT id FROM #__viewlevels WHERE rules LIKE '%$group%')";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    $nartigos=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
};

echo "Nº de artigos " .$nartigos;
```

Comment: #__content is th table name !! did you try to execute sql seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you really should normalize your data.  Consider having a many-to-many join table for viewLevels instead of having all groups in one row.  That might look like this:

```
access_id  group_id
1          10
1          12
1          15
2          8
2          11
2          12
3          5
3          9
3          10
```

That would make your query as simple as

```
SELECT c.id AS `content_id`, COUNT(v.access_id) AS `content_count`
FROM content AS c INNER JOIN viewLevels AS v
  ON c.access_id = v.access_id
WHERE v.group_id = ?
GROUP BY c.id
```

Here `?` is the group id you are querying against.

Without normalization (which again I STRONGLY recommend you do), you would still use a join, but it would look like this:

```
SELECT c.id AS `content_id`, COUNT(v.access_id) AS `content_count`
FROM content AS c INNER JOIN viewLevels AS v
  ON c.access_id = v.access_id
WHERE v.group LIKE '%?%'
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the second option but I still get the same error: undefined variable: nartigos. I will try to normalize the data as you recommend but I won't be able to change viewlevels table (it's a Joomla CMS)

Comment: @NunoNogueira You really don't currently have any error handling in your code to help show you where you are having problems.  I would recommend that you capture and inspect the values of each of your database operations so you can narrow down your problem.

Answer (score -3):

you need to "join" your tables.

the sql command cant query two tables seperately.

when you "join" 2 tables in your sql, think of it as making one virtual/temporary table in the air, of the 2 tables which you can then query.

this is quite a good intro http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: As is, this answer does not answer the question. Please expand on your answer, include references, or provide code.

Comment: dude, relax. this is the wholistic answer. this guides the op on to what area he/she needs to research into and learn more about. i believe they are (and find them) just as/if not more useful in the long term than just given the quick fix answer. but i will expand the answer for you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Prashant - see my comment i just left above